# Why doesn't my stylebox get overwritten correctly to my panel

Tags: godot, godot4

I need to use a programmatic stylebox overwrite, but for some reason it's not working. It says it's been overwritten, but continues to point to the default stylebox.

Here is some test code:

```
var panel = PanelContainer.new()
print(panel.has_theme_stylebox_override("normal"), panel.get_theme_stylebox("normal", "normal"))
    
var stylebox = StyleBoxFlat.new()
stylebox.bg_color = Color.from_string("#000000a0", Color.BLACK)
stylebox.corner_radius_bottom_left = 10
panel.add_theme_stylebox_override("normal", stylebox)
print(panel.has_theme_stylebox_override("normal"), panel.get_theme_stylebox("normal", "normal"))
```

Here is the output:

```
false<StyleBoxFlat#-9223372011084970892>
true<StyleBoxFlat#-9223372011084970892>
```

As you can see, despite being overwritten the stylebox is still pointing to the default for the theme.

Comment: I see you found a solution on reddit, maybe you can answer your own question? https://www.reddit.com/r/godot/comments/12zh2qq/godot_40_why_wont_my_ui_panel_stylebox_overwrite/

Comment: @JasperV great idea, will do that now :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was that I was using the wrong theme type. According to the [docs](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/4.0/classes/class_panelcontainer.html#class-panelcontainer-theme-style-panel), the correct type is `panel`.

i.e. the fixed solution is:

```
var panel = PanelContainer.new()
var stylebox = StyleBoxFlat.new()
stylebox.bg_color = Color.from_string("#000000a0", Color.BLACK)
stylebox.corner_radius_bottom_left = 10
panel.add_theme_stylebox_override("panel", stylebox)
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a little trouble figuring out similar trying to change the `BG Color`.

Standard RGB parameters didn't work but from an Html string it's ok.

This C# version demonstrates duplicating and overriding the themes panel.

```
// Called when the node enters the scene tree for the first time. -- Godot 4
public override void _Ready()
{
    //get labels from scene tree
    _nameLbl = GetNode<Label>("%NameLabel");
    _numLbl  = GetNode<Label>("%NumLabel");

    //get the stylebox & duplicate from this controls themes panel
    StyleBoxFlat sbf = GetThemeStylebox("panel")
        .Duplicate() as StyleBoxFlat;

    //print color to see what we have
    GD.Print("background colour panel stylebox: ", sbf.BgColor);

    //set color from html. Typical RGB values didn't work
    sbf.BgColor = Color.FromHtml("017f01");

    //add the override
    this.AddThemeStyleboxOverride("panel", sbf);
}
```